# utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte при открытии фото

Tags: python, django, byte

Имеется Django модель `user.path`, в которой лежит название фото в формате

```
"{:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}.png".format(datetime.now())
```

Тоесть вот такого вида `2018-01-19 12-17-07.png`

Пытаюсь отправить ее пользователю

```
ppath = 'путь к директории с фото'
photo = open(ppath + urllib.parse.unquote_plus(user.path))
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку

```
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: `open(..., 'rb')`

Comment: @andreymal ха, спасибо))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему `open(..., 'rb')` помогло?

Дело в том, что без по умолчанию `open` открывает файлы в режим чтения `r`. Этот режим включает в себя чтение массива байтов и приведение его к строке, используя указанную кодировку (или системную кодировку, если не указывать).

Файлы фотографий (картинок) являются *бинарными файлами*, поэтому попытка получения из них текста в указанной кодировке, скорее всего, вызовет ошибку:

```
ppath = 'путь к директории с фото'
photo = open(ppath + urllib.parse.unquote_plus(user.path))
```

Поэтому, открытие файла *в бинарном режиме* и помогло:

```
ppath = 'путь к директории с фото'
file_name = ppath + urllib.parse.unquote_plus(user.path)
photo = open(file_name, 'rb')
```